# Are visa application forms for Morocco available online?

Tags: visas, germany, morocco, frankfurt

I live in Germany but I am not a German citizen, therefore, I need to have a visa (tourist visa) to travel to Morocco.

I have been searching the ***Visa form*** on their website ([Consulate Morocco, Frankfurt](http://www.consulat.ma/an/prestations.cfm))  for 2 days but I could not find it out.

I found a travel visa form at this [link](http://visafrankfurt.de/Marokko/Marokko.htm) but it is not official.

Does anybody know where can I download the form OR if the form on the unofficial website is the correct form?

Comment: This link really helped to clear things up since the visa information is scattered around in so many places. I found somewhere that we need to pay:
• Gebührenmarke (aktueller Wert):
20 Euro (für die einfache Einreise)
30 Euro (zweifache Einreise) Does anyone know where can we get the Gebührenmarke? I know in France we had to buy them at a Tabac but not sure what the process is in Germany.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86947)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the french pages, the form is linked on the respective site: http://www.consulat.ma/fr/prestation.cfm?gr_id=6&id=53#serv - there is a PDF-Symbol at the top of the page that allows you to download the application form in RTF-format. The form is bilingual french/english.

Comment: Thanks, when I called to the Consulate, they told me to search for "Visumantrag (Visa Application)". Although I don't find "Visumantrag" written anywhere, I hope its the correct form.

Answer (score 6):

I recently applied for a tourist visa to Morocco from Germany and finally succeeded.

[Here](http://www.botschaft-marokko.de/node/38) is the link to the procedure and required documents. At the end of the page, there is a link to the visa application form which can be downloaded.

One has to send the filled out application form with the supporting documents (not original passport) via post to the consulate. There are three in Germany (Berlin, Frankfurt and Düsseldorf). You need to check which jurisdiction you fall under (which depends on the city you are registered in) and send your application to the corresponding consulate. I made a mistake of sending my application to a different consulate (Berlin) than to Frankfurt and got no response from them.

After about 2 weeks after sending your application, you need to get in touch with them and enquire about when you can collect your visa. They never contacted us and so we were constantly on the phone trying to reach someone at the consulate and finally succeeded and got an appointment for the stamping.

For collecting the visa, you need to go in person to the consulate with you original passport. Apparently from January, 2017 they have stopped sending and receiving the passports via post since there were instances when the passports were lost in transit.

Comment: thanks, thats a big help. I am wondering that the Form on the French page is of 3 pages and the German form is of 1 page only. Could you please tell me if the visa stamping can be done in a single day? I mean, once the visa is accepted the, would it be enough to go just once (I live far from Frankfurt so, can't go multiple times).

Comment: I did not take a look at the French form but the one page application served its purpose. In my case, once I got a positive response, it took a few hours at the consulate to get the passport stamped. I'm not sure about the other consulates though. Which city are you based in? Are you sure that you fall under the Frankfurt consulate's jurisdiction?

Comment: I live in Bavaria. I could reach them only once via phone and then told me that I should send my application to Frankfurt (which is nearest to Bavaria).

Comment: Their visa process is seriously quite confusing. The information is different on pages with different languages. On English and French page, they are asking to send 2 passport photos of size 4x3cm whereas, on this German page, they are asking 3 photos (no size specified). Did you affix a photo on the form too in addition to 3 photos?

Comment: I just pinned three pictures to the form and sent copies of the tickets, hotel reservation, bank statement from the last three months, passport copy and German visa copy along with the application form.